# Превью фотография для панорамы. ymaps.panorama

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Есть ли какая-то возможность получать превью фотографию панорамы по координатам объекта или метод для объекта panorama, для получения такой фотографии

Для аналогии, как это делается у google maps  в StreetView

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/streetview/intro?hl=ru

Answer (score 0):

В линейке API Яндекса сейчас нет продукта с превью панорам. Можно только создавать полностью плеер с интерактивной панорамой.